# How to send get or post request to Httpbin with params in PATH?

Tags: httprequest, http-get

I set httpbin backend path is `/get/{id}`,but response is 404

Answer (score 0):

No method `/get/{id}` in httpbin,`/cache/{value}` is useful for me.